# How to change the position of the menu in rsuite DateRangePicker?

Tags: reactjs, daterangepicker, rsuite

I'm using rsuite DateRangePicker and the component is displayed on the right. When I open the menu to select a date, the menu get out of the page container and I have to scroll the page to the right in order to see the entire menu.

[image: menu overflows]

I'm looking for a way to change the position of this menu, any idea?

Comment: It looks like they don't have a prop to achieve that. You should be able to do it with CSS.

Comment: @SamuelVaillant how can I apply directly CSS on the menu?

Answer (score 2):

DateRangePicker provides a `placement` property. You can set its value to `bottomEnd` or `auto`.

```js
<DateRangePicker  placement="bottomEnd" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `placement="auto"` to auto adjust the menu position.
More about placement usage, you can visit:https://rsuitejs.com/components/date-picker

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added `placement='bottomEnd'` and `preventOverflow`

```
<DateRangePicker
  size='md'
  placeholder='Select Date Range'
  block
  format='dd MMM yy'
  showOneCalendar
  placement='bottomEnd'
  preventOverflow
  ranges={Ranges}
  onChange={changeHandler}
/>
```

[image]